# Batch use of gotos and ()

Tags: batch-file

In a batch file you can have

```
Goto Stackoverflow
```

and you can have

```
(Goto Stackoverflow)
```

Whats the diffrence between these?

They are being used like this

```
:Stackoverflow
set /a x=%x% + 1
goto stackoverflow

:Stackoverflow
set /a x=%x% + 1
(goto stackoverflow)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses (or [brackets](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html)) are used in batch files specify a list of commands that should be treated as an entity, like `{ ... }` in other languages. Typically they are used with [IF](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) or [FOR](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) expressions:

```
IF EXIST %windir% (
    echo "one line"
    echo "another line"
)
```

In your example, there is no difference between `Goto Stackoverflow` and `(Goto Stackoverflow)`.

Comment: I have being using batch for a long time, but have never really asked if there was any differences with using the () in this example. Thanks